# Use try, catch when querytask times out using JS API

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

When I do a querytask and the date range criteria used is too vast, I get a 500 internal server error after 1.7 minutes every time (unless the query takes less than 1.7 minutes, then it runs fine). Is there any way I can use try, catch to let the user know the search has timed out.

I tried the following try, catch code but it does not do anything. It still says "Searching..." in my 'wait' div.

```
    function execute () {
            query.geometry = addressPoint;
            startDateQuery = document.getElementById("startDate").value
            endDateQuery = document.getElementById("endDate").value

            //esriConfig.defaults.io.timeout = 60,000;
            if (endDateQuery !== null && endDateQuery !== undefined && endDateQuery !== ""){
                query.where = "(DATE_VAL >= '" + startDateQuery + "') AND (DATE_VAL <= '" + endDateQuery + "')";
            }
            else {
                query.where = "DATE_VAL = '" + startDateQuery + "'";
            }
            try{
                queryTask.execute(query, showResults);
                document.getElementById('wait').innerHTML = "Searching...";
            }
            catch(err) {
                document.getElementById('wait').innerHTML = "Search timed out. Use a smaller search range.";
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would not have to define a try/catch statement. The *QueryTask* includes an [error callback](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/querytask-amd.html#querytask1). You could just define that function and insert your code into it:

```
queryTask.execute(query, showResults, errCallback);

function errCallback(){
    document.getElementById('wait').innerHTML = "Search timed out. Use a smaller search range.";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The third parameter a QueryTask takes is a handler for error

try catch is not reliable in JavaScript because of its async nature

do it this way

```
queryTask.execute(query, showResults, function(){
  document.getElementById('wait').innerHTML = "Search timed out. Use a smaller search range.";
});
```

Or you may pass in a defined function just like showResults